# Mapping constexpr class static to the class for a collection of classes

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, constexpr, parameter-pack

I have an extendable collection of classes that have approximately the same interface, that each have a different static constant for serialization purposes. Consider:

```cpp
class A {
    constexpr static int value = 0;
};

class B {
    constexpr static int value = 1;
};
```

Now, I'd like to do a reverse mapping from value to the class itself. I can do:

```cpp
template <int value> struct type_for_value { };
template <> struct type_for_value<0> { using type = A; };
template <> struct type_for_value<1> { using type = B; };
```

This works, however, every time I add a class to the collection (say class C), I have to add another template specialization. I also have other functions that use the entire collection of classes, such as:

```cpp
constexpr auto for_each_class(auto const& func) {
    return func.template operator()<A, B>;
}
```

Here I'd also need to add C to the parameter pack.

Is there any way to define the collection of classes once (maybe a macro, but preferably using something better typed like a single parameter pack), such that the template specializations are automatically generated at compile time, and that I can also use in the `for_each_class` function?

I tried to create a single struct with a parameter pack, like this:

```cpp
template <typename... T>
struct all_classes_impl {
    constexpr static auto for_each_class(auto const& func) {
        return func.template operator()<T...>();
    }

    template <int value>
    struct type_for_value { };

    template <>
    struct type_for_value<T::type> {
        using type = T;
    }...;
}

using all_classes = all_classes_impl<A, B>;
constexpr auto for_each_class = &all_classes::for_each_class;
```

But this doesn't work for the template specializations, and aliasing the `for_each_class` also does not work in this way.

Answer (score 2):

With a single point that needs to be edited if you add classes you can do this fairly minimally like

```
using type_list = std::tuple<A, B>;

template<int value>
using type_for_value_t = typename std::tuple_element<value, type_list>::type;
```

and then you can use it like

```
type_for_value_t<1> my_var;
```

and `my_var` will have the type `B`.

The only thing you need to maintain here is that the order of the types in `type_list` so that they are in the same index as their `value`.  This does mean you either need contiguous values or you add dummy types to the tuple where you have a hole.